# Ebay - Get Offer call for 10k items, Do I need to make 10k calls for getting Offer information?

Tags: ebay-api

I am reading listing item using getInventoryItems, I can read 200 items at a time.

I now have to read listing offers as well for each inventory item.

If I have 200 items, I will be making 200 calls to getOffer endpoint, 1 call for every inventory item and If I have 10k items in my store, then I would expect I will be hitting the limit soon and I have to fetch listing items every 2 hours.

Is this the only way to read listing items along with Offers (Offer includes price, quantity and sold items)?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `platform notification` with proper payload to be notified for any offer.

Advantage are many: you get offer details in real time and not every 2 hours and since you get offer details in the payload you do not need even 1 `GetOffer` call

Comment: How is your answer related to inventory items?

Comment: I do not have much experience with REST APIs  but platform notifications should work withany kind of item